# How would I go about integrating this?

Tags: integration

$$ \int_0^3 (x^2-3x).sin(\frac {n\pi x}3) $$

To my understanding I should use integration by parts but I am confused by the limits as they would be used twice in int by parts.

This is what I have done so far:

$$ u = x^2-3x $$

$$ \frac {du}{dx} = 2x -3 $$

$$ v = \frac {3}{n \pi}.cos( \frac {n \pi x}{3}) $$

$$ \frac {dv}{dx} = sin( \frac {n \pi x}{3}) $$

Then put this into the integration by parts equation $ \int uv - \int v.\frac {du}{dx} dx $:

(Skipping to $ \int v.\frac {du}{dx} dx $)

$$ \frac {3}{n \pi}.cos( \frac {n \pi x}{3}).(2x-3) $$

$$ [ \frac {6x-3}{n\pi}.cos(\frac{n\pi x}{3})]_0^3 $$

Substituting $ x $ with $ 0 $ gives $ 0 $.

Sub $ x $ for $ 3 $.

$$ \frac {15}{n \pi}. \frac {3}{n \pi}.cos(n \pi) $$

$$ \frac {45}{n^2 \pi^2} . cos(n \pi) $$

$$ [\frac{3x^2-9x}{n \pi}.cos(n \pi) + \frac {45}{n^2 \pi^2}.cost(n \pi)]_0^3 $$

Is this correct so far? When I go ahead and put in the limits I get the following which doesn't seem to be correct:

$$ - \frac{27}{n^2 \pi^2}.cos(n \pi) + \frac {45}{n^2 \pi^2}.cost(n \pi) $$

Comment: You got the right idea. Whenever you have $\int \text{polynomial}\times \text{(Trig. function or exponential)}$, you want to use integration by parts in such a way that you reduce the degree of the polynomial until you end up with just $\int \text{trig. function or exponential}$.

Comment: I've added in the answer I get but when putting it on an "integration calculator" it doesn't seem to output the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should certainly use integration by parts but a lot of your details seem to be incorrect.

First, your $\frac{dv}{dx}$ is correct but $v$ is wrong.

Second, the formula $\int uv - \int v.\frac {du}{dx}$ should be $uv - \int v.\frac {du}{dx}\,dx$.

Third, in the following line the $\frac{du}{dx}$ term should be $2x-3$ not $3x/n\pi$, and the $v$ term is different from above but still wrong.  Also you do not seem to have integrated this line.

Comment: I have made some edits.

Comment: My first point: your new $v$ is still wrong.  My second point: you haven't corrected the formula.  My third point: you have fixed $\frac{du}{dx}$ but you still have not done the integration.  Sorry if I sound negative but I think you need to sit down with your teacher/instructor and go through all this, not try and fix it online.