# Integrate By parts $x^5 e^{-x^2}$ polynomial times exponential

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $x^5 e^{-x^2}$ and $3x^2 2^{x^2}$

I'm not sure what to do about the $x^2$ part when I integrate. Can I get hints?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774941/how-would-i-go-about-integrating-this#comment1608162_774941) comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, substitute $t=-x^2,dt=-2xdx$; then
$$\int x^5e^{-x^2}dx=\int-\frac12x^4e^{-x^2}(-2xdx)=\int-\frac12t^2e^tdt=(-\frac12t^2+t-1)e^t=(-\frac12x^4-x^2-1)e^{-x^2}+C.$$

The second problem is a nonelementary integral. Let
$$I=\int3x^22^{x^2}dx=\int3x^2e^{(\ln2)x^2}dx=\int3x^2e^{(\sqrt{\ln2}\ x)^2}dx.$$
Substituting $t=\sqrt{\ln2}\ x$ we get
$$I=\int at^2e^tdt\text{ where }a=\frac3{(\ln2)^{3/2}}.$$
This is a nonelementary integral, just like the familiar nonelementary integral $\int e^{t^2}dt$; in fact, integration by parts shows that
$$\int e^{t^2}dt=te^{t^2}-\int2t^2e^{t^2}dt=te^{t^2}-\frac{2I}a.$$

Comment: +1 But, why not $t=-x^2$?

Comment: Well, I guess the point behind the substitution is to make the thing as easy as possible to integrate and $e^{t}$ is easier than $e^{-t}$. Obviously, not a big deal, but that's what I usually tell my students.

Comment: @MarkMcClure OK, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkMcClure What about $\int (3x^3)(2^^(x^(2))dx$? Can we also substitute $x^2$ to t? In other words, find the integral of $3x^3$ times $two$ to the $x^2$ power dx.

Comment: @Ben Are you sure you copied the second problem correctly? A substitution will reduce it to $\int t^2e^{t^2}dt$ but that's a nonelementary integral, just like $\int e^{t^2}dt$. In fact, integrating by parts, $\int e^{t^2}dt=te^{t^2}-2\int t^2e^{t^2}dt$.

Comment: yes, getting the answer involves not changing t to x^2 while one solves the integral. in other words, keep x^2 as t for as long as possible

Comment: I edited my answer to say something about the second problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the first integral, try $u = x^4$, $dv = xe^{-x^2}\,dx$, and integrate by parts.  You can deal with the second one similarly.

Comment: how did you get $u=x^4$?

Comment: You need an $x$ so you can integrate the $dv$.  What is this with the commentless downvote??

Comment: since it is difficult to do anything about the $e^{-x^2}$ piece, try to keep enough with it to allow for an easy substitution to calculate later, hence $dv = xe^{-x^2}dx$.  $u=x^4$ is because it is everything that is still left after deciding what $dv$ had to be to make things work out nicely for us.

Comment: Got my upvote - though, it might be worth mentioning that you'll get something that looks like $x^3e^{-x^2}$ and you'll need to do it again before getting an integral that can be done with substitution.

Comment: Iterate. Once you see something and it brings you in the right direction, REPEAT.

Comment: @ncmathsadist could I use the same method for integrating $sec^3(x)) dx$?

Comment: Yes, use $dv = \sec^2(x)$ and integrate by parts